# How to remove Toolbar goes transparent with a tint

Tags: java, android, oop

I have made a new method in my app to set certain text and items to colors, as themes. But for some reason when I code it in a OOP way I get the toolbar to be tinted for some odd reason.

With the non OOP method i get:
https://gyazo.com/6084992a654573b85adfe0c01077627e

```
public void setOffTheme(){
    slotsActivity.getToolbar().setTitle("\"Roulette\"");
    slotsActivity.getPlaceBetText().setHint("\"Bet\"");
    slotsActivity.getInstructions().setText("\"Pick a color\"");
    slotsActivity.getStart().setText(" \"Start\" ");

    Typeface tf =Typeface.createFromAsset(getResources().getAssets(), "Helvetica Bold.ttf");
    slotsActivity.getInstructions().setTypeface(tf);

    slotsActivity.getThemeImage().setImageResource(R.drawable.offtemplate);
    slotsActivity.getmConstraintLayout().setBackgroundColor(getTheColor( R.color.colorAccent));
    slotsActivity.getColorSpinner().setBackgroundColor(getTheColor( R.color.colorOffWhite));

    slotsActivity.getInstructions().setTextColor(getTheColor(R.color.colorGucciBlack));
    slotsActivity.getPlaceBetText().setTypeface(tf);
    slotsActivity.getPlaceBetText().setTextColor(getTheColor(R.color.colorGucciBlack));
    slotsActivity.getPlaceBetText().setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGucciBlack) ));

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.my_spinner_style, slotsActivity.getBettingColors()){
        //changes color of the drop down and selected
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            ((TextView) v).setTextSize(16);
            ((TextView) v).setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorGucciBlack) );
            ((TextView) v).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

            return v;
        }

        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
            ((TextView) v).setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorGucciBlack) );
            v.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(settingsActivity.this, R.color.colorOffWhite));
            ((TextView) v).setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);

            return v;
        }
    };

    slotsActivity.getColorSpinner().setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    slotsActivity.getStart().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonshapeoff);
    slotsActivity.getStart().setTextColor(getTheColor(R.color.colorGucciBlack));
    slotsActivity.getStart().setTypeface(tf);
    slotsActivity.getToolbar().setBackgroundColor(getTheColor(R.color.colorOffWhite));
}
```

While the OOP code shows: https://gyazo.com/15e2ded1ccdc5a7514c370651c638499

```
//this is the call to the method
      setTheme(R.color.colorAccent, R.color.colorOffWhite, R.color.colorGucciBlack, R.drawable.buttonshapeoff,R.drawable.offtemplate,"\"Roulette\"","\"Bet\"","\"Pick a color\"", " \"Start\" ","Helvetica Bold.ttf");

// this is the method
public void setTheme(final int backgroundColor, final int primaryColor,  final int textColor,int buttonShape, int templete,String title,String betName,String pickName,String startName,String typrface){
    Typeface tf =Typeface.createFromAsset(getResources().getAssets(), typrface);
    slotsActivity.getInstructions().setTypeface(tf);

    slotsActivity.getToolbar().setTitle(title);
    slotsActivity.getPlaceBetText().setHint(betName);
    slotsActivity.getInstructions().setText(pickName);
    slotsActivity.getStart().setText(startName);

    slotsActivity.getThemeImage().setImageResource(templete);
    slotsActivity.getmConstraintLayout().setBackgroundColor(getTheColor( backgroundColor));
    slotsActivity.getColorSpinner().setBackgroundColor(getTheColor( primaryColor));

    slotsActivity.getInstructions().setTextColor(getTheColor(textColor));
    slotsActivity.getPlaceBetText().setTypeface(tf);
    slotsActivity.getPlaceBetText().setTextColor(getTheColor(textColor));
    slotsActivity.getPlaceBetText().setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(textColor) ));

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.my_spinner_style, slotsActivity.getBettingColors()){
        //changes color of the drop down and selected
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            ((TextView) v).setTextSize(16);
            ((TextView) v).setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(textColor) );
            ((TextView) v).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

            return v;
        }

        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
            ((TextView) v).setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(textColor) );
            v.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(settingsActivity.this, primaryColor));
            ((TextView) v).setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);

            return v;
        }
    };

    slotsActivity.getColorSpinner().setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    slotsActivity.getStart().setBackgroundResource(buttonShape);
    slotsActivity.getToolbar().setBackgroundColor(primaryColor);
}
```

Comment: Compare the `slotsActivity.getToolbar().setBackgroundColor()` call you have in the first block with the one you have in the second block.

Comment: @MikeM. but the values are the same, in the 1st one the color is a constant while the 2 one  the color is passed as a param. you can see the call for the method at the top of the 2 method. ================= ================= ================= ================= ================= 

                                                                        setTheme(R.color.colorAccent, R.color.colorOffWhite, R.color.colorGucciBlack, R.drawable.buttonshapeoff,R.drawable.offtemplate,"\"Roulette\"","\"Bet\"","\"Pick a color\"", " \"Start\" ","Helvetica Bold.ttf");

Comment: Look more closely. What are you missing in the call in the second block? `R.color.colorOffWhite` is not a color; it's a resource ID.

Comment: @MikeM.    is it the ? but i doubt that changes anything slotsActivity.getStart().setTextColor(getTheColor(R.color.colorGucciBlack));
I tested it, it doesnt

Comment: "is it the ?" – Huh?  "but i doubt that changes anything slotsActivity.getStart().setTextColor(getTheColor(R.color.colorGucciBlack));" – I'm talking about the `slotsActivity.getToolbar().setBackgroundColor()` call. I'm not sure what `getStart()` would return. Anyway, you're missing the `getTheColor()` call in the second version of `slotsActivity.getToolbar().setBackgroundColor()`. As mentioned, `R.color.colorOffWhite` is not a color, but a resource ID, so when you set it as a color value, it's not going to be the color you set as the resource's value.

Comment: @MikeM. OHHH OK thanks so much idk how i skipped that